# Typescript Module not found

Tags: angular, typescript

I have defined a module like this in `target.d.ts`

```
declare module "target" {

    export interface Group {
        name: string;
        targets?: Target[];
    }

    export interface Target {
        device: Device;
        property: Property;
        value?: Value;
    }

    export interface Value {
        value: number;
        id?: number;
        timestamp?: number;
    }

    export interface Property {
        id: number;
        name: string;
        channel: number;
        type: string;
    }

    export interface Device {
        id: number;
        name: string;
        type: string;
    }

}
```

Now I am using the defined interfaces in a component like

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

import {BackendUrl} from '../../../../common/settings';
import {contentHeaders} from "../../../../common/headers";
import {EventService} from "../../../../service/event.service";

import {Input} from "@angular/core/src/metadata/directives";
import {Message} from "stompjs";
import {Target} from "target";

@Component({
selector: 'device-switch',
templateUrl: './switch.component.html'
})
export class SwitchComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input()
    public title: string;

    @Input()
    public device: any;

    @Input()
    public property: any;

    private checked: boolean;

    constructor(public authHttp: AuthHttp, private eventService: EventService) {
        this.checked = false;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.eventService.messages.subscribe(this.on_next);
    }

    /** Consume a message from the eventService */
    public on_next = (message: Message) => {

        let data : Target = JSON.parse(message.body);
        if(data.device.id === this.device.id && data.property.name === this.property.name) {
            this.checked = (data.value.value > 0);
        }

    };

}
```

The problem is that the `@Input()` variables `device` and `property` are interfaces types defined in my `target` module too.

But if I `import {Target, Device, Property} from "target";` the compiler throws an error

```
ERROR in ./src/app/component/view/part/device/switch.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'target' in '~/git/xx/frontend/src/app/component/view/part/device'
@ ./src/app/component/view/part/device/switch.component.ts 16:0-28
@ ./src/app/component/view/part/group.component.ts
@ ./src/app/app.module.ts
@ ./src/main.ts
@ multi main
```

I don't know whats the problem ... Intellij does not highlight anything ... seems to be ok.

Answer (score 3):

The most likely cause of your error is that your definition file is not being included in the compilation context, so that your `declare module 'target'` is never called.

There are several ways you can chose to include it:

1. Add `///<reference path="path/to/your/target.d.ts" />` to the top of your switch.component.ts.
2. Add `path/to/your/target.d.ts` to the `"file":[]` array in your `tsconfig.json`
3. Add `path/to/your/target.d.ts` (or an equivalent file pattern that would match it) to the `"include":[]` array in your `tsconfig.json`.

Once you get the `target.d.ts` included in  your compilation context then you should be able to `import {Target, Device, Property} from 'target'` anywhere in your application.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue in an Angular 7.2.0 project, updating to 7.2.8 solved it.

In my case I needed to force the update and resolve a typescript dependency:

`ng update --all --force`

followed by

`npm install --save typescript@">=3.1.1 <3.3.0"`